# Extending template in Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to write a custom DOM helper similar to `dom-if` and `dom-repeat` which extends `template`. It takes an attribute say partial name. Based on this partial name it would make an ajax response and get actual content part of template which has Polymer data binding markup also. So it basically needs to do lazy render of content.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry, question is how I change the content of template in polymer dynamically once I receive the ajax response. How do I render the markup based received template.

Comment: Initially there is no content

Comment: <template is="dom-lazy" partial name="xyz.tpl" ></template> this line is basically inside the main template of a Dom modul .

Comment: Added a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/8HD0gNERiFSl7qNKdJc0?p=info